# OData Creating a Service Operation to return a value to an IPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, odata

All i want to do is create a simple Service Operation in my .net OData solution that returns an integer value. Than on the IPad I will suck this integer value up using the OData Obj-c SDK. Here is my service op so far:

```
<WebGet()> _
Public Function GetWorkOrderNumber() As Integer
    Return DomainModel.SystemOption.GetWorkOrderNo
End Function
```

This returns the following when you hit it from the browser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<GetWorkOrderNumber p1:type="Edm.Int32" xmlns:p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">112</GetWorkOrderNumber>
```

When I try to call this operation from the IPad i get the entire response value. All I want is the value 112. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or need to change?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can append `$Response content` to the URL.  But yeah, I thought the proxy classes would give a better way.  I'm still looking.